# User authentication details in user details table or seperate?

Tags: database, authentication, passwords, schema

I have a user table which has all the user details like name,email, password hash, gender, city, education, etc... about 45ish columns in total.

The question is: Should i normalize this into two tables one for the user authentication, that is user_id, email, password_hash, password_salt.

And second table to hold user details or is it ok to have both in 1 table? I cant normalize the user details too much because this is a critical system and performance is very important so need to keep joins low.

I am just concerned if user password/email used for login authentication should be in a separate table for better security or not?

Comment: How is a separate table "better" security?  What makes you think "separate" == "better"?  Did you read this somewhere?

Comment: "password hash" - I want you to know that, as a general user of the internet, I appreciate this.  I often see authentication-related questions on SO where the person asking provides code demonstrating plain text password storage.  You've actually brightened my afternoon ever so slightly.  Thank you.

Comment: Nope not read it but from real world experiences, you don't store your super secret stuff with your normal stuff. They are stored separately. My secret files will be in a bank locker. My personal files may be in my home safe. So I thought break out the tables then see what else is needed to protect the authentication table.

Comment: well plain text storage people should not be allowed to do development. There should be a SO ban on these people. Security and privacy are so important nowadays and are a must on every system.

Comment: "you don't store your super secret stuff with your normal stuff"?  Why not?  I still don't get the distinction you're making.  All data is private.  All parts of a system must be secure.  Why would separating things make security "better"?  If there's no real reason (just a vague analogy with banks and homes) why bother?  All computer storage must be equally secure.  What distinction are you making?  I don't understand.  Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

Two tables wouldn't inherently provide additional security over one table unless those tables are implemented in very different ways.  Say, for example, they're partitioned off to different hardware and the password table has native disk encryption or something like that.  And even then we're talking about different forms of "security."  Both tables are still live and in use, one would just be encrypted at rest.  (There may be other examples, but that's all I can think of right now.)

Personally, I tend to use two tables not from a security point of view but rather from a separation of concerns point of view.  One is authentication, one is the user profile.  In the vast majority of cases they don't need to be separate, but I prefer to keep them separate just in case a logic change is required that needs them to be separate, since they are logically not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony's sfGuard uses two tables: one for authentication data, other for user details. That looks rather sensible - as this separates two different sets of data from each other, and the user auth table is narrow, thus it fits better into memory (and various caches) and doesn't need to operate with the (wider) user details whenever authentication is needed.

As for security, I don't really see a difference in one table vs. two tables, except maybe in backup storage requirements.

As always, measure and compare how this stacks up in *your* specific situation.